# Make maven project from custom nexus repositories

Tags: java, maven, repository, nexus, archetypes

I made my custom nexus repository on remote, and I've already made a custom archetype and deploy it to the repository.

Actually, Now I want to make maven project from the archetype which is on that custom nexus repository.

I've set the remote repository info in .m2/settings.xml.
and I tried "mvn archetype:generate" .
But I cannot see my custom archetype in the archetype catalog list.

If I try -D option ( mvn archetype:generate -DremoteRepositories=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/nexus/content/releases/ ), I can see the archetype that I made.

Is there another way to make maven project from custom remote repositories?

One more Question,
about the url, if I try "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/nexus/, the archetype-list can't be found. do I have to inform the exact location where archetype-catalog.xml exists? Actually I want to make several archetypes and inform the location of custom repository to my team members to use the archetype that they want case by case.

Looking forward to answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked all around book and found it.

Actually, I made a mistake on settings.xml file

First I put the  tag for my custom remote repository.
in the mirror tag, there is a mirrorOf attribute.
I have to set mirrorOf tag as "*". ( it means all request should be applied to this mirror tag )

Second. I've missed the url.
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/nexus/content/releases/ ==> it was wrong.
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/nexus/content/groups/public ==> this is the right url

I posted my question and answer by myself.
someone refer to this.

Thanks.